# Is it a general truth that when two equations can be described with the same sentence, only varying intonation they are equivalent?

Tags: intuition

My question is the effect of something that I have noticed during some of the courses I am taking as a first year maths bachelor, that in tutorials we will be asked to proof that two statements are equal but that when I try to describe the left and right hand side I end up with one and the same sentence, I will give three examples:
\begin{equation}
    (A^m)^{-1} = (A^{-1})^m
\end{equation}
Both the left and right hand side are described by the sentence "the inverse of matrix A to the power of m"
\begin{equation}
f^{-1}(A\cap B) = f^{-1}(A) \cap f^{-1}(B) 
\end{equation}
With both A and B being supsets of the real numbers, both the left and right hand side are described by the sentence "the values that when the function f is applied to them end up inside set A and also inside set B", something similar can be done replacing the intersect with a union and the 'and' with an 'or'.
\begin{equation}
    (AB)C = A(BC)
\end{equation}
This example is discussed in three blue one browns series on linear algebra, both the left and right hand side are described as "first apply transformation C, then transformation B, and finally transformation A"

Of course, the fact that two sides are described the same is not a rigorous proof since it could be that sneaky business is applied in words with double meanings - although often that should be easy enough to spot - but I do think this is a rather interesting patern and I would absolutely love to know if anyone can come up with an example where both the left and right hand side are described the same and still not equal.

Comment: FWIW I don't buy your second example: "the values that when the function f is applied to them end up inside set A and also inside set B" to me only refers to $f^{-1}(A\cap B)$. And if we do accept that that can also refer to $f^{-1}(A)\cap f^{-1}(B)$, it seems to me that we have to also accept that "the set of values $f$ takes on given inputs from $A$, and also from $B$" can refer to either $f(A)\cap f(B)$ or $f(A\cap B)$, which of course are not equal in general.

Comment: For a more basic example, how about "$x$ minus $y$ plus $z$?" This could refer to either $(x-y)+z$ or $x-(y+z)$, which of course are not equal in general.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because ....i'm not quite sure how to explain it. mathematical statements are not about intonation. if something is unclear, then let's clarify. (i still upvoted the question though lol)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sentences you provide lack punctuation. Hence they are (potentially) ambiguous. Whereas "the inverse of matrix A to the power of m" uses correct syntax, semantically it is ambiguous. It does not adequately describe either $(A^m)^{-1}$ or $(A^{-1})^m$.

Intonation is a form of verbal punctuation which is applied by someone who interprets a sentence. Verbally there are homophones, homonyms and homographs - so it depends on whether the sentence is spoken or written. Context can also be necessary as a clue to the intended meaning. Furthermore, the structure of sentences (syntax) can differ between languages.

So I think there is no general answer to your question, and the question itself is not mathematically interesting. It merely highlights the inadequacies of spoken languages for mathematics.

In mathematics 'punctuation' is provided by brackets (and other conventions such as BODMAS) rather than by intonation. Sometimes also the context is crucial in interpreting a mathematical statement. In mathematics it is essential to avoid all ambiguity. Mathematics is a written language rather than a spoken language. Verbal intonation has no role.

Answer (score 0):

*Mathematica* has a `Speak` function, where (for instance)

`Speak[x^2]`

will produce the aural utterance "x squared."

`Speak[(x y) z]` and `Speak[x (y z)]` each give the identical utterance "x times y times z," where of course these need not be equal in non-associative algebras.

Comment: I'd like to argue that although you might be speaking the formula, you are not describing it. Much in the same way I gave the example of (AB)C = A(BC) which I would describe as "first apply transformation C, then transformation B, and finally transformation A" not as A times B times C, since that description is really only speaking out the characters on the page and does not insightfully describe either side of the equation.